# Prototype JS - Can't chain element.previous(0).match()

Tags: prototypejs

Long story short, I've had a long story here but reduced it to Q&A to help others!

I had the following loop:

```
$$('#leftCntr label').each(function(elem){
    if($(elem).previous(0).match('h3'))
    {
        console.log($(elem).previous(0).innerHTML);
    }
});
```

it didn't work... but the problem was very obvious...

**i had to check if there really IS a previous, otherwise you can't chain the functions**

Answer (score 1):

Some elements don't have previous elements... -_- but only parents ofcourse,,
It only took me 3 to 4 hours to solve this |-)
So I hope I could help someone with this!!!

```
$$('#leftCntr label').each(function(elem){

    if($(elem).previous(0) && $(elem).previous(0).match('h3'))
    {
        console.log($(elem).previous(0).innerHTML);
    }

});
```

p.s. just starting with a stackoverflow account because it's just the best site around for stuff like this and I want to help too!! :) I hope to provide you people with more of my solutions to awkward problems when I encounter them!